# Compactification of the set of probability measures

Tags: probability, general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider the set $\mathcal M (\mathbb R)$ of all (Borel) probability measures on $\mathbb R$ corresponding to distributions of real-valued random variables. Prokhorov's theorem says that a subset of $\mathcal M (\mathbb R)$ is compact with respect to the topology of weak convergence if and only if it is tight. Since $\mathcal M (\mathbb R)$ itself isn't tight, it is not compact.

However, it seems that the set of *subprobabilities* $\bar{\mathcal{M}}(\mathbb{R})$, defined to be all measures integrating to at most 1, is a compactification of  $\mathcal M (\mathbb R)$. That is, it is compact with respect to a topology whose subset topology on $\mathcal M (\mathbb R)$ is the topology of weak convergence. It is suggested in [Chen (2017)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-32/issue-1/Consistency-of-the-MLE-under-Mixture-Models/10.1214/16-STS578.full#:%7E:text=An%20incorrect%20claim%20of%20consistency,spite%20of%20recent%20research%20breakthroughs.), [Kiefer-Wolfowitz 1956](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-27/issue-4/Consistency-of-the-Maximum-Likelihood-Estimator-in-the-Presence-of/10.1214/aoms/1177728066.full), and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507102), though without further proof.

Is there a relatively elementary, intuitive exposition of this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, consider $K$, the one point compactification of the line. The space of probability measures on $K$ is compact, and is homeomorphic to the space of subprobability measures on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Neat! two silly questions: (1) $\mathcal{M}(K)$ is compact because $K$ is compact and hence  $\mathcal{M}(K)$ is tight? and (2) is it true that if $X \subset Y$ as topological spaces, then $\mathcal{M}(X) \subset \mathcal{M}(Y)$ as topological spaces?

Comment: (1) Yes, because $K$ is compact and metrizable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures#Compact_spaces   $\quad$ (2) Yes, $\mathcal M(X)$ is homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathcal M(Y)$ via the natural embedding.